# Android animation rotation

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I want to make an imageview rotate with an animation. This is going well with this code: `imageView.animate().rotation(degrees).start();` But the problem is that when the degrees goes from 0 to 360, the animation will make a whole round, this is not what I want. I want to make it go like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

res/anim/anticlockwise.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate android:fromDegrees="360"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>
</set>

 Animation anim = 
 AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.anticlockwise);
            imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what should happen. Passing a degree of 360 is a full rotation, thus returning the ImageView to it's original orientation. You need to pass in the actual degree you wish for the ImageView to be rotated.

Comment: So what you say is, that I have to use something different to accomplish the kind of animation that I want?

Comment: You just need to pass in a different value inside of rotate(...). The value of 360 is causing it to fully rotate around it's center axis and thus causing it to return to it's starting position. Maybe try a value like 30 or 60.

Comment: I am making an compass that is able to go from 1 to 350, or 0 to 360 degrees. So of course 30 or 60 degrees is going to work just fine. But I also want to handle 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: @JelleO I'm sorry then I'm confused what your problem actually is because passing in 360 will always rotate a view back to starting position. Your code is doing exactly what it should.

Answer (score 0):

@JelleO, As you were working to create a rotation animation for compass, the following rotation logic should work on your requirement.

```kotlin
fun rotate(azimuth: Float) {
    var from: Float = mlastAzimuth
    var to: Float = azimuth
    val min = Math.min(from, to)
    if (Math.abs(to - from) > 180) {
        if (min == from) {
            from += 360f
        } else {
            to += 360f
        }
    }
    mlastAzimuth = azimuth

    val anim: Animation = RotateAnimation(-from, -to, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)
    anim.fillAfter = true
    anim.duration = 200
    compassImage.startAnimation(anim)     
}
```